# Logstash converting date to valid joda time (@timestamp)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Hope someone can help me out!

I have a question about logstash. I grok the following date with succes: 26/Jun/2013:14:00:26 +0200

Next, I want this date to be used as the @timestamp of the event. As you know logstash automatically adds a timestamp.

Replacing the timestamp that logstash is adding can be done by the date filter. I have added the following date filter: match => [ "date", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z"]

But, for some reason, that doesn't work. When I test it out, I see that logstash just adds his own timestamp.

Code:

```
grok {
    type => "log-date"
    pattern => "%{HTTPDATE:date}"
}

date{
    type => "log-date"
    match => [ "date", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z"]
}
```

I need to do this, so I can add events to elasticsearch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to contact people via the IRC channel and for so far, no one could help me out. I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the following approach:

```
# strip the timestamp and force event timestamp to be the same.
# the original string is saved in field %{log_timestamp}.
# the original logstash input timestamp is saved in field %{event_timestamp}.
grok {
  patterns_dir => "./patterns"
  match => [ "message", "%{IRODS_TIMESTAMP:log_timestamp}" ]
  add_tag => "got_syslog_timestamp"
  add_field => [ "event_timestamp", "%{@timestamp}" ]
}

date {
  match => [ "log_timestamp", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}

mutate {
        replace => [ "@timestamp", "%{log_timestamp}" ]
}
```

My problem now is that, even if @timestamp is replaced, I would like to convert it to a ISO8601-compatible format first so that other programs don't have problems interpreting it, like the timestamp present in "event_timestamp":

```
     "@timestamp" => "Mar  5 14:38:40",
       "@version" => "1",
           "type" => "irods.relog",
           "host" => "ids-dev",
           "path" => "/root/logstash/reLog.2013.03.01",
            "pid" => "5229",
          "level" => "NOTICE",
  "log_timestamp" => "Mar  5 14:38:40",
"event_timestamp" => "2013-09-17 12:20:28 UTC",
           "tags" => [
    [0] "got_syslog_timestamp"
]
```

You could convert it easily since you have the year information... In my case I would have to parse it out of the "path" (filename) attribute... but still, there does not seem to be an convert_to_iso8901 => @timestamp directive.

Hope this helps with your issue anyway! :)

Comment: I just solved the path issue with an extra grok: `grok {
     match => [ "path", "%{YEAR:log_year}" ]}`

Comment: More pointers on this particular example over here: https://gist.github.com/brainstorm/6552989

Comment: Followup on this topic on logstash mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/4GRVY9UJEU4

Comment: will this feature be incorporated instead of having to role this out each time?

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is just a work around !, try to add **`locale => "en"`** to your code.
If not added, the date **weekdays and month names** will be parsed with the default platform locale language (spanish, french or whatever) and that's why it didn't work (since your log is in english).

```
date{
    type => "log-date"
    match => [ "date", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z"]
    locale => "en"
}
```

Comment: Agree. Had date parsing errors. My `LANG` env variable was set to `fr_CA.UTF-8` Adding `locale => "en"` enabled logstash to properly parse logs shipped from system with date formatted in english.